# Listing the files and revisions with a certain check-in message in Subversion

Tags: svn, message, commit

In SVN, is there a way to list files based on a commit message?

Answer (score 0):

"svn log  | grep ..." is probably the easiest way from the command line. TortoiseSVN can search in log messages directly.